# How to estimate the true rank of a matrix, given an estimation of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, statistical-inference, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix $A$ and an estimation of the matrix $\hat{A} = A + \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is some noise.

I want to estimate $m = \text{rank}(A)$, but only have access to $\hat{A}$. How could I do it? I have tried to look at the singular values, but it is not clear where to put the threshold.

Comment: You should ultimately decide the threshold based on the distribution of $\varepsilon$. For instance, if you could find an $\alpha$ for which $\|\varepsilon\|_F \leq \alpha$ with high probability, then it could make sense to use $\alpha$ as your singular value threshold

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to predict the rank of $A$ exactly unless $\hat{A}$ has full rank because for every $n$ less than the full rank the set $\{A: \mathrm{rank}(A) > n\}$ is dense in the set of all matrices. However, you can estimate the rank from below if $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small. This is because
$$\|s_k(A) - s_k(\hat{A})\| \leq \|A - \hat{A}\| \leq \varepsilon$$
for all (ordered) singular values $s_k$. Hence if the largest $n$ singular values of $\hat{A}$ are larger than $\varepsilon$, then $A$ has at least rank $n$.

Comment: I know it is impossible to predict, but I just want to estimate, so its ok if it is not the exact rank. Also, $\varepsilon$ is not scalar, is a matrix describing the error. You can think of it as a random variable.

Comment: @DiegoPalacios That will obviously depend on the distribution of your $\varepsilon$. But unless your distribution of $\varepsilon$ is very specific, $A$ will always have full rank almost surely because, as I mentioned above, the matrices of full rank are dense.